# Why not getting rounded corners of image view once image is placed?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-selector

Here is my layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >





        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/round"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundp" 
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

roundp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners 
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>

   <stroke 
       android:width="2dp"
       android:color="@color/red" />
   <solid 
       android:color="@color/white"/>


</shape>
```

round.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners 
        android:topRightRadius="25dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="25dp"/>

   <stroke 
       android:width="2dp"
       android:color="@color/red" />
   <solid 
       android:color="@color/white"/>


</shape>
```

If I don't place any image in ImageView I can see empty ImageView with rounded corners, after placing image rounded corners are gone, normal rectangular shape is shown with image. How to fix this issue ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it sometimes does not show in emulator or graphical layout try to run it on a real device and check

Comment: checked on device still not getting rounded corners after placing image, if i run code without placing image it shows empty imageview with rounded corners.

Comment: try using match_parent as width for your imageView

Answer (score 0):

put the gradient in the shape xml..

```
<gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#fddd"
        android:startColor="#ffff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have been using layout_weight attribute,
but you haven't used weight_sum attribute anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

For the **round** , u can add **android:padding** to display the boarder.

However, for the **roundp** , i have no idea to fix it unless dealing with the image by code java.

Comment: what i said above is that, your round.xml describe a right angle then u can use padding to fix it. however, for your roundp.xml, i suggest u to code java dealing with the round corners.

Answer (score -1):

there is the code to add rounded corners for image

```
public static Bitmap toRoundCorner(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {  

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);  

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);  

    final int color = 0xff424242;  

    final Paint paint = new Paint();  

    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());  

    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);  

    final float roundPx = pixels;  

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);  

    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);  

    paint.setColor(color);  

    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);  

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));  

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);  <br>
    return output;  

}
```